# LINQ - Return data from list 2 occurrences

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of int called "motor_list" = 2, 3, 5, 3, 8, 5, 5, 9, 8   (List 2)

```
(3 = 2 times in the list)
(5 = 3 times)
```

I have a table (Item), which content row "ItemId, Name, Date, Location", and it's only content 2 datas :

`(ItemId) = 3 and 5.    (List 1)`

```
var data = _context.Item.Where(x => motor_list.Contains(x.ItemId));
```

Using the above code, I'm only getting two data which is obviously right technically,

now I want to get data but according to the occurrence of motor_list (List 2),
and no the one for Item table.

I mean I want to get something like :

```
ItemId 3 should pull 2 times the same data, and
ItemId 5 should pull 3 times.
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"pull 3 times"*? Do you want the count of that item id in the motor list? Or you just want the data returned in a list of 3 identical items instead of a single item? It would be helpful if you used actual code to illustrate the results you expect returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join to return exactly the items in the `motor_list`.

```
var data = motor_list
           .Join(_context.Item,
           left => left,
           right => right.ItemId,
           (left, right) => new { items = right });
```

or a little further away

```
var data = _context.Item.ToList();
var result = lst.Select(x => new
     {
        item = data.Where(a => a.ID == x).FirstOrDefault()
     }).Where(a=>a.item != null).ToList();
```

Comment: @Meysan I know a bit of LINQ, but how can I master LINQ / Lambda ? Any books suggestions please Meysan ?

Comment: @User456 There are many books to search on the Internet, but you have to practice, and the Visual Studio environment itself is a book. In the Visual Studio environment, constantly work with different functions and test to understand the concepts. Of course, it takes some time and I still have a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
    List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 3, 5 };
    List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 5, 3, 8, 5, 5, 9, 8 };

    var data = list2.GroupBy(x => x).Where(a => list1.Contains(a.Key));

   var result=   data.Select(g => $"ItemId {g.Key} should pull {g.Count()} times").ToList();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by *"ItemId 3 should pull 2 times the same data"*. It sounds like you either want the count of each ItemId in motor_list, or you want the duplicate items returned in the results.

Here's how you can accomplish either:

```
class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Item> contextItems = new List<Item> { new Item { ItemId = 3 }, new Item { ItemId = 5 } };

    var motor_list = new List<int> { 2, 3, 5, 3, 8, 5, 5, 9, 8 };

    // To get the count of each contextItem in motor_list:
    var itemCount = contextItems
            .Select(contextItem => 
                motor_list.Count(motorId => motorId == contextItem.ItemId))
            .ToList();

    // result: { 2, 3 }

    // To get duplicate items for each contextItem in motor_list
    var items = motor_list
            .Where(motorId => 
                contextItems.Any(contextItem => contextItem.ItemId == motorId))
            .ToList();

    // result: { 3, 5, 3, 5, 5 }
}
```